# chrome.tabs.query not passing message to content.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am stuck in a basic program just when I started learning chrome extension. My program is to build an extension which has button to change the color of the webpage. Changing color should be action driven that is why I didn't use default css to change the color on page load. Below are my files. The problem that I have is chrome.tabs.query in background.js is not returning tabs array and I get "ID not referenced error"
Any help is appreciated. I have searched n number of articles on google and StackOverflow but nothing is helping me

Files:
manifest.json

```
    {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Hello world",
"description": "Demo extension",
 "version": "1.0",

 "icons":
{
"16": "images/dog.png", 
"48": "images/dog.png",
"128": "images/dog.png"
},

"background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

"browser_action":
{
"default_icon": "images/dog.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
  }],

"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*","activeTab"]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch(message.type) {
            case "setcolor":
                chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tab){
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id,{type: "setcolor",color: message.color})
                });
                break;
            default:
                console.error("Unrecognised message: ", message);
        }
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>


<p id="demo">Click below button to change color of page</p>

<button type="button" id = "red"> RED </button>
<script src = "myscript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

myscript.js (or popup.js)

```
function color(colorval) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "setcolor",color: colorval})
}

document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', color('red'));
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = message.color;
        }
);
```

Comment: 1) `Tab tabs` describes the type in the documentation, it's not a valid JS syntax, 2) See also [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029), 3) there's no need for background script here as you can do the same in the popup's script.

Comment: @wOxxOm I was using only tabs initially and still wont work. Was just playing around so included Tabs tab. It wont work anyway. I get same error “id not referenced”. I have edited the code in the question since thats how i am using function(tab). I know we can achieve through different methods but thisis a basic example where i want to establish communication between popup, background and content. The actual usage is different once I am able to solve this basic example.

Comment: addEventListener line is wrong, it should be addEventListener('click', () => color('red'));

Comment: Wow! This worked. () => color('red')

Comment: @wOxxOm how do I upvote your answer. I mentioned you in the answer section so it reflects on your profile. Sorry as I am new to the forum

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `Tab` as the first argument from your callback.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
   // your message logic
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was using it the way you suggested. I should have reviewed before posting. I just updated the code in the question. It is not working that way. I was playing with Tabs tab but actual code is function(tab) which is not working. Please let me know .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wOxxOm for solving this. I was using the below function in a wrong way.

Old code:

```
document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', color('red'));
```

New code:

```
document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', () => color('red'));
```

or

```
document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', fucntion() {color('red')});
```